# What are some sentient creatures of pre-Columbian Mesoamerican mythology?

Tags: mythical-creatures, comparative, native-american, mesoamerica, aztec

I have read a bit about the [five suns world creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Suns) myth, and I am curious if the original peoples of Mesoamerica believed in other sentient beings similar to the fairies, centaurs and such of European mythology and folklore.

I have read about the "wood people" but I am curious if there are more.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you specify what you have read about the "wood people"? The more thorough the question the better we can help you. I already took the liberty of editing tags and links, if this is not ok feel free to change it back.

Comment: @Tom Certainly, I haven't been able to get much info on the wood people, but apparently the gods Kukulkan and Tepeu first tried to form people out of mud, but this disintegrated, then wood, but the people had no souls and lost loyalty to the gods, then finally out of maize, which worked.